# Windows Server 2008 R2 - automatic & transparent backup of LAN user's documents

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, local-area-network

First, as I'm not a native speaker, please bear with my primitive english...

I've got a server running 2008 R2 and clients connected to it on a small sized LAN (few dozens machines). The server is a domain controller (dns and dhcp servers running) The hardware is quite old, pentium D 2.66Ghz.
Client machines are not always connected to the domain.

I've been tasked to set up a simple backup solution that would be automatic and transparent for the users, i.e requiring the least amount of interaction from users. When clients connect to the domain, their documents (e.g windows well known folders) should be backed up to the server, with incremental backups and space quotas per user.

I see there are many ways to achieve this, but I'm trying to find the one that makes most sense for this configuration, something lightweight, easy to set up and manage, and ideally free.

As of now I'm fiddling with UrBackup, wich allows fine-grained configuration. I'd like to deploy the client version of the software silently via a GPO and configure it such that the user has nothing to configure (the folders to backup in particular).

I'd like to have a few leads and clues as to what are to most common solutions to this kind of problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using "Folder Redirection" along with the associated Windows Server feature "Offline Folders".

[Windows Server TechNet - Offline Files and Folder Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/gg277982.aspx)

**Folder Redirection** can solve the primary issue of Windows user data/folders consolidation allowing your choice of backup solution to target one location as the source for backup of all user folders.  The typical scenario is to redirect "Documents" and "Desktop" to a network attached storage location, but any shared, network storage location could be used provided it has sufficient space, etc.  A user opening a Word file from their "Documents" folder would actually be accessing the data in the redirected location, rather than on the local machine.  I have not personally found the technology to be a significant performance hit on the network, but of course each situation is different.

**Offline Folders** provides additional local caching of the redirected user data by synchronizing the state of the remotely located user data with a local store.  As long as your users are not off-domain for days or weeks on end, this would provide the second part of your solution.  Users working off-domain in this situation would work from the local, cached copy until connection to the domain is again established at which point the two stores, redirected and local, would synchronize.

The combination of the two Windows Server 2008 features would allow a much simplified backup of user data.  Following setup of Folder Redirect and Offline Folders, simply point your backup application to the redirected storage location and all user data will be backed up.  One other caveat, this requires a little user education to ensure they are not saving important company files in non-redirected locations (such as directly on [C:]).